# How turn off Mendeley Desktop automatically syncing

Tags: windows, sync, mendeley

Using the Mendeley Desktop Application, all references added to the library will be automatically 'synced', i.e. uploaded. How can I stop Mendeley's automatic synchronization?

User -> Preferences opens the Online Account options, which contains no synchronisation options.
User -> Settings opens only one setting related to groups, with the hint "more settings coming soon".

I know I can turn off Sync by selecting a file, and then un-ticking the "Mendeley Catalog" option, but I can't find a way to change this default to 'off'.

Mendeley Version: 2.61.1